# How is the author's application of the law of total expectation consistent with the definition?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I have the following solution:

> Let $$Y_j = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if $j$th toss is a head} \\ 0, & \text{if $j$th toss is a tail} \end{cases}$$
>
> Let $X$ denote the waiting time to $HH$. First, we note that, if any toss is a tail, then the experiment regenerates. In particular, if $Y_1 = 0$, then the experiment regenerates. Therefore, we have that
>
> $$E[X \vert Y_1 = 0] = E[X] + 1.$$
>
> On the other hand, for the case where the first toss is a head, the law of total expectation -- with extra conditioning on $Y_1 = 1$ -- gives us that
>
> $$\begin{align} E[X \vert Y_1 = 1] &= \sum_{y = 0}^1 E[X \vert Y_2 = y, Y_1 = 1] P(Y_2 = y \vert Y_1 = 1) \\ &= E[X \vert Y_2 = 0, Y_1 = 1] P(Y_2 = 0) + E[X \vert Y_2 = 1, Y_1 = 1] P(Y_2 = 1) \end{align}$$

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) gives the law of total expectation as follows:

> If ${\displaystyle {\left\{A_{i}\right\}}_{i}}$ is a finite or countable partition of the sample space, then
>
> $${\displaystyle \operatorname {E} (X)=\sum _{i}{\operatorname {E} (X\mid A_{i})\operatorname {P} (A_{i})}.}$$

How is the author's application of the law of total expectation consistent with the definition?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this.

Comment: I guess you're talking about the second one.  The events that partition the space are $Y_2=0$ and $Y_2=1$.  Why is that a problem?

Comment: @saulspatz well, the definition states that it is summing over all *individual* events $A_i$ that partition the space, whereas the author is summing over *multiple* events $A_i$, $A_j$ that partition the space. It is not clear that the definition, as written, allows the latter. So I’m curious if there’s an extension to the definition, or if what the author has is actually consistent with the definition.

Comment: $Y_2=0,Y_1=1$ means the intersection of the two events, $Y_2=0$ and $Y_1=1$, and the intersection of two events is an event.  There's no problem at all.

Comment: @saulspatz Oh, ok, I see what you mean. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @saulspatz Actually, what about the $P(A_i)$? For the expected value terms, the author uses the event $Y_2, Y_1$, as you say, but for the $P(A_i)$ terms, the author uses only the individual events $Y_2 = 0$ and $Y_2 = 1$. Shouldn't $Y_1$ be part of those terms?

Comment: If you look at the formula, he first multiplies by $\Pr(Y_2=y|Y_1=1)$  But $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent, so  $\Pr(Y_2=y|Y_1=1)=\Pr(Y_2=y)$

Answer (score 1):

To answer "How is the author's application of the law of total expectation consistent with the definition?"

I think the Tower Property can explain it better. [Tower property:
For sub-σ-algebras $\mathcal H_1\subset \mathcal H_2\subset \mathcal F$ we have $$ E(E(X\mid \mathcal H_2) \mid \mathcal H_1)= E(E(X\mid \mathcal H_1)\mid \mathcal H_2)=E(X\mid \mathcal H_1)$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation)

Define $\mathcal H_1=\sigma(Y_1)$ and $\mathcal H_2=\sigma(Y_1,Y_2)$ so $\mathcal H_1 \subset \mathcal H_2\subset \mathcal F$ 
$$\begin{align} \mathbb E[X \vert Y_1 ] &\overset{\text{Tower property}}{=} \mathbb E\left( \mathbb E[X \vert Y_1 ] \mid Y_1,Y_2\right) 
\\ &\overset{\text{Tower property}}{=} \mathbb E\left( E[X \vert Y_1 ,Y_2 ] \mid Y_1\right) 
\\ &= \mathbb E\left( g(Y_1 ,Y_2 ) \mid Y_1\right) 
\\ &= \sum_{y}  g(Y_1 ,Y_2=y )\mathbb  P(Y_2 = y \vert Y_1 ) 
\\ &= \sum_{y } \mathbb E[X \vert Y_2 = y, Y_1] \mathbb P(Y_2 = y \vert Y_1 )= \cdots \end{align}$$